# What is the difference between $-\sqrt{x}$ vs $\sqrt{-x}$

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

What is the difference between them?
And why $\sqrt{-1}$ is imaginary?
I see nobody use negative square root number but only square root negative number? Sorry for my grammar and sound confusing but I really want to know why
Nobody used $-\sqrt{}$ instead $\sqrt{-}$?

Comment: We use $-\sqrt{x}$ very often. I do not see the problem here. $\sqrt{-1}$ denotes a quantity whose square is $-1$. Do you know any real number whose square is $-1$? On the other hand, for example, $-\sqrt{1}=-(1)=-1$, which is real.

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you believe that $\sqrt {-1}=-\sqrt 1 = -1$?

Comment: ask yourself what the difference between $-2^2$ and $(-2)^2$ is, and extrapolate

Comment: No I don't think that √-1 = -√1. Okay it's -4 and 4

Comment: In Complex Analysis, $-\sqrt{x} = (-1) \times \sqrt{x}~$ while $~\sqrt{-x} = \sqrt{-1} \times \sqrt{x},~$ where, depending on convention and the specific value of $~x,~$ you have that $~\sqrt{-1}~$ equals either $~+i~$ or $~-i.$

Answer (score 1):

Here are three [graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFa8o.png):

- $y_1 = \sqrt{x}$
- $y_2 = -\sqrt{x}$
- $y_3 = \sqrt{-x}$

Depending on where the negative sign is, it either flips $\sqrt{x}$ about the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis.  You can convince yourself that this works by picking a number like $x = 4$:

- $y_1 = \sqrt{4} = 2$
- $y_2 = -\sqrt{4} = -2$
- $y_3 = \sqrt{-4} = ?$ (that graph doesn't exist when $x>0$, which is why the answer is imaginary)

But it does where $x = -4$:

- $y_3 = \sqrt{-(-4)} = \sqrt{4} = 2$